# How to detect if the bootstrap mobile nav is open or not?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know if is it possible to detect if a bootstraü mobile navbar has been opened or not using jquery.

The class which opens the navigation is called **navbar-toggle**

```
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-
   target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">
```

Comment: Well go check if the relevant element has the class that makes it “open” then ...

Comment: Post code as text, not an image!

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery:

```
if ($(".navbar-toggle").hasClass("collapsed")) {
  // Closed
} else {
  // Open
}
```

You should use id if there are multiple `.navbar-toggle`